# Why are only installed chromium extensions listed

Tags: chromium

On a new laptop, I installed Lubuntu 18.04 from an.ISO. Then, on the new laptop, I installed Chromium from the available software list. Chromium synced with Chromium on another laptop and inherited the extensions used by the other laptop. But, when I search for extensions on the new laptop, Chromium displays only the installed extensions -- not others that might be available. How can I find out what other extensions are available?

Comment: At the Chrome extension store? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "hamburger" menu from within the Extension page and click on "Open Chrome Web Store". Alternatively you can go to this URL: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions

[Image of Hamburger Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQeiv.png)

[Chrome Web Store Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYqqo.png)